# Order of "subscribing" Spring Integration Flows when using Java SDL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Referencing rather ancient question [Spring Integration "Publish Subscribe Channel" with Spring DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658104/spring-integration-publish-subscribe-channel-with-spring-dsl), I need to know wether it is possible to determine / declare the order of which subscribers of a publish/subscriber-channel will be called.

Reason: I am receiving files from a remote directory to transfer them into a database and delete afterwards. Of course, deletion shall only happen, if writing to the database completed successfully.

Code from referenced question is:

```java
@Bean
public SubscribableChannel  httpInAdapterPubSubChannel()
{
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe("httpInAdapterPubSubChannel")
    .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subscriber1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(httpInAdapterPubSubChannel())
            .handle( message -> System.out.println("Enrich Headers based on Payload...."))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subscriber2() {
     return IntegrationFlows.from(httpInAdapterPubSubChannel())
                .handle( message -> System.out.println("Save Payload to Audit Table..."))
                .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `order` is an attribute of the endpoint which is going to subscribe to the channel. In your case we have those two `.handle()` endpoints and here is an option how to configure:

```
.handle( message -> System.out.println("Enrich Headers based on Payload...."),
           e -> e.order(1))

 .handle( message -> System.out.println("Save Payload to Audit Table..."),
           e -> e.order(2))
```

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-endpoints